# 64 bit arithmetic with 16 bit word length(store 64 bit number across 4 words)

Tags: math, assembly

I am currently writing software for a 16 bit custom microprocessor. I need to be able to deal with numbers larger than 16 bits. The instruction set is quite limited, but has left shift, right shift, AND, OR, and NOT. How would I implement this type of arithmetic?

Comment: Left shift and bitwise and & or are sufficient.

Comment: Could you specify what arithmetic operations do you need to support? Do you know if there is C implementation for your µcpu?

Comment: addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. There is unfortunately no C implementation. I don't want to have to edit the processor itself, so I think the best way is to split the number's binary representation across an array of 4 words, and then manipulate those arrays. However, I am not so clear on how to do this.

Comment: Are there instructions to get the high half of a multiplication and to divide a double-with number by a normal one? Add-with-carry would be nice too but it's trivially emulated.

Comment: WHat part do you have trouble with? Accessing the arrays? Or performing the operations?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Only 16 bit registers, basic instructions for arithmetic, and the bitwise operators I mentioned in the question :/

Comment: Performing the operations efficiently. Obviously the easiest way is to write an addition function that carries the overflow from one word to another, and multiplication would just be serial addition, but this is slightly inefficient.

Comment: Multiplication would just be 64 multi-word right-shifts and 64 conditional multi-word additions (only performed if the operand that you're shifting is odd), not too bad. For division you could just use restoring division.

Comment: What are CPU's options for working with the carry bit? On Intel, there's the super-convenient ADC ("Add with carry") command. On ARM, you can have a conditional upon carry.

Comment: No options for working with the carry bit. I thought I'd just write a function to emulate ADC haha.

Also, thanks for all the great comments guys!!

Comment: I skipped 64 multi-word left-shifts there but that doesn't change much..

Comment: No carry? So how are you supposed to perform unsigned integer comparisons?

Comment: I'd have to specify another register to hold a carry bit and manually perform the carry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For addition and subtraction, you do indeed carry the overflow from one word to another. For multiplication, the technique described at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier is a reasonably easy thing to implement and is better than serial addition. Division is more complex in general, but a good place to start is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Integer_division_.28unsigned.29_with_remainder.

That division algorithm is really just an integer "long division". Not terribly fast, but it's accurate. The article has more involved methods, but they're ... well, more involved. Probably get the easy one going and then see if you need to optimize it.

Also take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm. And http://x86asm.net/articles/working-with-big-numbers-using-x86-instructions/ has some good information on multi-word arithmetic on x86 processors, much of which should be applicable to other CPUs.

It's been too long since I played with this stuff. Having done 32-bit arithmetic on the Z80 (many, many years ago), I have some idea what you're up against here.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks :) We're trying to write a mandelbrot set generator on a simple 16 bit processor written by 1 guy, and it's not very fun xD This will definitely help us though!

Comment: A Turing tarpit if there ever was one.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants code to do this, I'm writing it at the moment.  I have 64 bit multiply working as of last week, so now I'm working on 64 bit divide.  The code will be on https://github.com/drtonyr or send me an email.   Contacting me is the best way, as the code below is non-standard (I intend to write/build everything, including soldering transistors), but  if it helps, then in outline it looks like this (in a Forth like language):

```
: 4mul pick(7) pick(4)        # grab the sign words
  xor mvDC                    # compute final sign and put on call stack
  4abs 4swap 4abs 4maxmin     # abs swap so that second is smallest
  callocC(4)                  # zero space on call stack for result
  allocC(4)                   # space for smallest multiplier
  storeC(1) storeC(2) storeC(3) storeC(4) # smallest to C in reverse order
  C add(8) D sub(2)              # set up pointers for main _4mul_word calcs
  mvCD _4mul_word _4mul_word_asl # mul X0
  mvCD _4mul_word _4mul_word_asl # mul X1
  mvCD _4mul_word _4mul_word_asl # mul X2
  mvCD _4mul_word                # mul X3
  ndrop(7)                    # don't need X3, pointers or shift space anymore
  4mvCD                       # move result to data stack
  mvCD <0 if? 4negate         # set correct sign
  ;                           # and exit happy
```

Much of that is data movement, but the idea is to have a 64 bit result and the largest number which is shifted up by one every cycle, then pick off the bits of the smallest number and add in to an accumulator if the bit is set, which is achieved by _4mul_word (_4mul_word_asl just completes the shift when the top bits are zero).  One day I'll optimise further as the smallest number is likely to have lots of zeros at the top and the whole thing can stop once you've processed the top bit of the smallest number.    _4mul_word is below, but the main take away here is that (a) you can do it and (b) it's a lot of work and runs slowly.

```
_4mul_word:  # top of stack contains the top address of accumulator (D),
             # the top address of partial shifted input (A) and
             # the word to multiply (B).
             # This runs over all non-zero bits.
  *C = E, C -= I  # store E
  *C = D, C -= I  # store D - we will leave stack state unchanged

  B = *D, D -= I  # pop the main word we are going to work with
  A = *D, D -= I  # Address of partially shifted
  D = *D, D -= Z  # Address of accumulator

  _4mul_word_loop:
    Z = B & I         # test a single bit
    eq0 P = *P, P += I  # skip if bit is zero
    :_4mul_word_bitzero
      *C = A, C -= I  # store A as we are going to change it
      *C = D, C -= I  # store D as we are going to change it
      *C = B, C -= Z  # store B as we are going to change it

                      ## add in the shifted value (A) to accumulator (D)
      B = *D, D -= Z  # read X0
      E = *A, A -= I  # read Y0
      B = B + E       # compute Z0
      *D = B, D -= I  # and store it
      B = *D, D -= Z  # read X1
      E = *A, A -= I  # read Y1
      cin B = B + E   # compute Z1
      *D = B, D -= I  # and store it
      B = *D, D -= Z  # read X2
      E = *A, A -= I  # read Y2
      cin B = B + E   # compute Z2
      *D = B, D -= I  # and store it
      *D = B, D -= I  # and store it
      B = *D, D -= Z  # read X3
      E = *A, A -= I  # read Y3
      cin B = B + E   # compute Z3
      *D = B, D -= I  # and store it

      B = *C, C += I  # restore B
      D = *C, C += I  # restore D
      A = *C, C += Z  # restore A
    _4mul_word_bitzero:

                    ## shift up the contents of A
    *C = A, C -= Z  # store A as we are going to change it
    E = *A, A -= Z  # read X0
    E = E + E       # compute Z0
    *A = E, A -= I  # and store it
    E = *A, A -= Z  # read X1
    cin E = E + E   # compute Z1
    *A = E, A -= I  # and store it
    E = *A, A -= Z  # read X2
    cin E = E + E   # compute Z2
    *A = E, A -= I  # and store it
    E = *A, A -= Z  # read X3
    cin E = E + E   # compute Z3
    *A = E, A -= I  # and store it
    A = *C, C += Z  # restore A

    B = B >> I      # shift down B
    ne0 P = *P, P += I  # loop if we haven't yet shifted down B to zero
    :_4mul_word_loop

  C = C + I
  D = *C, C += I  # restore D
  E = *C, C += Z  # restore E
  P = *E, E += I  # execute the NEXT code
```